# SQL query to fetch rows which are not same for a given group

Tags: sql, select

For example for a table as below

```
c1      c2      c3
a       b       1
a       b       2
c       d       1
c       d       1
e       f       3
e       f       3
e       f       3
x       y       5
```

In this scenario I want the group value of c1, c2 where <strike>all</strike> at least one of the c3 is not same. So in this case (a, b) as one row of (a, b) is 1 and another row of (a, b) is 2.

Also row (x, y) must not be reported.

Comment: And if (g, h, 1), (g, h, 2) and (g, h, 2) are values you don't want (g, h) returned either right? Only return `c1` and `c2` if **all** `c3` values differ?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the logic behind your expected results. Why should (x, y) not be reported? And what would happen with the (g, h) from my earlier comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  c1, c2
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY c1, c2
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c3) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8230/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════╗
║ C1 ║ C2 ║
╠════╬════╣
║ a  ║ b  ║
╚════╩════╝
```

but of you want to get all the rows with all its columns

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  c1, c2
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY c1, c2
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT c3) > 1
        ) b ON  a.c1 = b.c1 AND 
                a.c2 = b.c2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8230/10)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦════╦════╗
║ C1 ║ C2 ║ C3 ║
╠════╬════╬════╣
║ a  ║ b  ║  1 ║
║ a  ║ b  ║  2 ║
╚════╩════╩════╝
```

Comment: If you add (g, h, 1), (g, h, 2) and (g, h, 2) to the values, these queries will also return (g, h). I'm not sure that's what the asker is looking for...

Comment: @Josien exactly because the c3 are different.

Comment: Hm yeah, I'm in doubt because of the 'where all c3 are not same' statement in the question. Difference between 'some c3 should differ' and 'ALL c3 should differ'. But I think we need some more information :-)

Comment: You are right @Josien., I should have been very clear. The result I am looking for is if any one(or more) of the c3 differs then report it.
Thank you JW. I accept this as the answer I was looking for and "COUNT(DISTINCT c3)" is something I have to learn about.

Comment: You can also use this if you want to check if all values are different: **HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C3) = COUNT(\*)**

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
    WHERE t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
    AND   t1.c3 <> t2.c3
)
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8230/9/0) (if you just want one record, use `t1.c3 < t2.c3`)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: BAsed on single pairs not being included:

If you want to get each pair, C1,C2, for which every value of C3 is different, the following will do it:

```
SELECT
    C1,
    C2
FROM
    dbo.Table1
GROUP BY
    C1,
    C2
HAVING
    COUNT(1) = COUNT(DISTINCT C3)
AND COUNT(1) > 1
```